# Manually freeze X server

Tags: linux, testing, freeze, xorg

Is it possible to manually freeze the Xorg display server on Linux? If so, how?

This would be for testing purposes. I think that there are a lot of situations this could be useful for, but I currently want to use this to test Linux's ability to recover with SysRq keys from X freezing.

Comment: If it was possible, it would be a bug in `Xorg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might send a `SIGSTOP` signal to `Xorg` with

```
 sudo pkill -STOP Xorg
```

and later send it a `SIGCONT` signal.